# Why is Visual Studio / Resharper still slow after upgrading memory?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

[ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) suggests 4 GB of memory.  I just upgraded my PC from 512 MB to 4 GB of memory (I have a [Dell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell)). Is there anything I need to do in Windows after installing this memory or should it be good to go right now?   I was expecting to see a big boost in Visual Studio but it still seems slow.

Comment: I very recently installed 4.5 and found a few weird gremlins: like I save a file and VS2008 takes 7 seconds to become responsive again.

Comment: I think Resharper is excellent, but I would have to question their adviceon requiring 4GB that seems excessive!

Comment: Like other commenters told you. The fact that your machine had a stock configuration of 512 MB ram is a clear indication that it is several years old and that you are not only low on memory but even more CPU bound. In short your machine is hopelessly oudated. Get a new one instead of investing into the old one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the new Resharper 4.5 release. They've done lots to improve speed.

You can also turn of some of the Visual Studio Intellisense options so VS doesn't do the same work as R#.

To disable VS IntelliSense:

1. Tools | Options
2. Text Editor | C# | IntelliSense
3. Uncheck "Show completion list..."
4. Text Editor | C# | Formatting
5. Uncheck all 3 options

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Solution-Wide Analysis option enabled, this may eat a lot of memory and cause performance problems. It's best to leave it off unless doing project-project refactoring or for the occasional code analysis.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the type and most importantly the size of your project. Resharper has always been a huge performance killer when working with large web projects like ours because it seems to have trouble coping with lots of aspx and ascx files. Our solution consists of 24 subprojects and 328 aspx pages using 640 ascx controls and sometimes it takes up to 20 seconds to open an ascx in text view (let alone design view). And our machines at work are equipped with 4GB of Ram and some with 8GB.

Answer (score 1):

I had several problems with resharper that eventually led me to uninstall it completely. I am happy with the performance but could have been happier with resharper.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about memory. You only need a good CPU (they recommend a quad core.)

I have ReSharper 4.5 on a [Core 2 Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#Core_2_Duo) and 2 GB of RAM. It takes 15 to 30 seconds to start Visual Studio but after that everything is smooth.

Comment: Cause of the statement of Paul i think this might be a good suggestion. Because if its a dell deliverd with just 512 MB of Ram its sure severals years old!

Comment: @Richard : I would say he has a single core processor with something around 2Ghz

Answer (score 1):

I personally chose to uninstall R# 6.0 after giving it a try. Performance price is just too high. 
My dev PC is Win7 32-bit 4GB RAM, I mostly work on an MVC3 solution with about 40 projects in it. Even with on-the-fly analysis turned off, takes several seconds to display intellisense menu, which is a big no-no to me.
Plus suspending R# (Tools, Options, Resharper, Suspend) causes intellisense to not work any more (does R# replace VS intellisense completely?).
Too many serious drawbacks to an otherwise interesting product with many pluses.

Answer (score 1):

I could see all the performance related problems are because the machines have less FSB speed (RAM speed).  It is similar to how fast your processor messages consumed by the other components. The FSB speed needs to be higher (e.g. 1333/1600/1833 MHz) along with higher clock CPU and SSD for better development experiences.